# storing comma separated values in cookie using ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies

I am trying to save comma separated values in a cookie, i am working on ruby on rails. but when i fetch the cookie i see that "," is converted to %2C.

I am not sure what am i doing wrong, any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Below is how i am saving cookie

```
cookies[:gridSettings_orders_order] = {:value => "48,78,198,58,98,62,78,118,98,148,128,78,78,178,53,53,43,128,118,43,78,98,148,98|48,78,198,58,98,62,78
,118,98,148,128,78,78,178,53,53,43,128,118,43,78,98,148,98||0,1,4,2,3,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16
,17,18,19,20,21,22,23"}
```

but when i fetch the cookie i get

```
48%2C78%2C198%2C58%2C98%2C62%2C78%2C118%2C98%2C148%2C128%2C78%2C78%2C178%2C53%2C53%2C43%2C128%2C118%2C43
%2C78%2C98%2C148%2C98%7C48%2C78%2C198%2C58%2C98%2C62%2C78%0A%2C118%2C98%2C148%2C128%2C78%2C78%2C178%2C53
%2C53%2C43%2C128%2C118%2C43%2C78%2C98%2C148%2C98%7C%7C0%2C1%2C4%2C2%2C3%2C5%2C6%2C7%2C8%2C9%2C10%2C11
%2C12%2C13%2C14%2C15%2C16%0A%2C17%2C18%2C19%2C20%2C21%2C22%2C23
```

Answer (score 0):

You can decode that by simply doing `URI.decode("...")`

Comment: you mean when i am creating the cookie i should use decode? Because i am creating the cookie in ruby and accessing it in javascript.

Comment: @opensource-ios when you are accessing the cookie value

Comment: i am supplying the cookie to a dhtml grid, isnt there a way where i can store the cookie value without ","

Comment: DHTML grid? What are you trying to do exactly?